# FTP files directly to Media Library wp-content\uploads

Tags: media

I would like to use an automated process to replicate a non-WordPress file folder in \wp-content\uploads\ and have the files automatically registered in the Media Library.

I could use such a process to upload the files, then register them using Add From Server (http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) or the similar Media From FTP. But that seems like excessive human input.

LR/Blog (http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrblog.php) appears to be able to save to WP and register the files at the same time. How can this be done with any files using a command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/commands/media/import/) for that. It's the (in)official WordPress command line tool, like Drush for Drupal or the Symfony2 Console Component.

Use the `media` command to handle your (future) attachments:

```
wp media import <file> [--option=value*]
```

** Take a look at the docs or the CLI help tool to see what options you got.*

> `wp media import` produces WordPress `attachment` post types from plain files, therefore letting them appear as uploads in the WP media library.

Examples from the docs.

```
# Import all jpgs in the current user's "Pictures" directory, not attached to any post
wp media import ~/Pictures/**\/*.jpg

# Import a local image and set it to be the post thumbnail for a post
wp media import ~/Downloads/image.png --post_id=123 --title="A downloaded picture" --featured_image

# Import an image from the web
wp media import http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png --title='The WordPress logo' --alt="Semantic personal publishing"
```

*(current state of code base while writing this question - later readers, read the docs on the official site)*